# Nightwatch - Wait for text in a list of elements, for a period of time

Tags: nightwatch.js

using Nightwatch, I need to look at a list of HTML elements, and determine if any of them have a specified message, within a certain time period.  (i.e. Using mailtrap.io to test outgoing emails - the emails may be queued and not arrive for 5 to 10 minutes).  I have the following:

```js
this.expect
    .element(mailtrap.elements.messages.selector)
    .text.to.contain(message)
    .before(600000)
```

This does not work as it only appears to check the first element it finds when the command is executed.  It does not seem to update it's list before it checks again.

I know I could do `clients.elements('css selector', mailtrap.elements.messages.selector, function (result) {...})` to get an array of matching elements and possibly check each.  Before I start down that path though, is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: `client.elements()` is your best option here. As you can see, `.element()` only returns one element and it is always the first one that it finds unless you tell it otherwise.

Comment: I started down the path of using the `.elements()` method.  I got it about 90% of the way there then ran into asynch issues with the elementIdText() method for each of the items from .elements().  This is probably a limitation of my knowledge, but I found using .execute() worked in my case.  (I posted an answer below with my "solution")

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in a round about manner.  First I created a custom command - `waitForTextInCollection` - modeled after the example class based command in the docs, and a [Github](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/246) answer.  I'm posting it here for the public record, but it should be heavily vetted before making use of it yourself.

The solution in my case is that we just wanted to ask the page if the text appeared in a collection of elements.  So using the `.execute()` method gave me an easy way to do that without having to rely on asynchronous routines (besides .execute).  The results from the execute function feed into the callback method where I decide if we need to wait another interval or if we are done.  Beforehand, things were getting nasty with `.elements()`, and `elementIdText()`.

Promises would be a great addition here, but I found mixing and matching between the older callback methods and the newer promises methods were getting confusing (to this dev).

My custom command:

```js
let util = require("util")
let events = require("events")

// Build the initial function prototype for our command
function waitForTextInCollection() {
  events.EventEmitter.call(this)
  this.startTimeInMilliseconds = null
  this.checkIntervalInMilliseconds = null
}

// Inherit from the event emitter
util.inherits(waitForTextInCollection, events.EventEmitter)

// Build the actual command to be called
waitForTextInCollection.prototype.command = function(
  collectionSelector,
  targetText,
  waitTimeout,
  callback
) {
  // if the waitTimeout is not specified, use the global timeout value
  if (typeof waitTimeout !== "number") {
    waitTimeout = this.api.globals.waitForConditionTimeout
  }

  // add some data to 'this' to support our work
  let self = this
  this.startTimeInMilliseconds = new Date().getTime()
  this.checkIntervalInMilliseconds = this.api.globals.waitForConditionPollInterval
  this.timeoutInMilliseconds = waitTimeout

  // call the check routine and then handle any results via the callback
  this.check(collectionSelector, targetText, function(result, elapsedTime) {
    let message = 'waitForTextInCollection: "'
    if (result) {
      message += targetText + " was found (" + elapsedTime + "ms)"
    } else {
      message += "text NOT FOUND after " + waitTimeout + " ms"
    }

    self.client.assertion(result, "NOT FOUND", targetText, message, true)

    // the self.emit('complete') has to be called from an async method, 
    // otherwise the command succeeds and then just hangs.
    setTimeout(function() {
      self.emit("complete")
    }, 100)
  })

  return this
}

// The method to check if we have found the desired text yet
waitForTextInCollection.prototype.check = function( collectionSelector, desiredText, callback ) 
{
  // determine "now" and the elapsedTime in milliseconds
  let self = this
  let now = new Date().getTime()
  let elapsedTime = now - self.startTimeInMilliseconds
  if (elapsedTime > self.timeoutInMilliseconds) {
    // we've exceeded the desired timeout period, so fail the command
    callback(false)
    return
  } else {
    // define a collection of data to pass to the page
    let myargs = {
      selector: collectionSelector,
      desiredText: desiredText
    }

    // ask the page itself to tell us if the text exists at this time
    self.api.execute(
      function(data) {
        var titles = []
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll(data.selector)
        var found = false
        elements.forEach(function(el) {
          if (el.textContent == data.desiredText) {
            found = true
          }
        })
        return found
      },
      [myargs],
      function(result) {
        if (result.value) {
          // Text was found
          callback(true, elapsedTime)
        } else {
          // Text does not exist (yet) so schedule another check
          setTimeout(function() {
            self.check(collectionSelector, desiredText, callback)
          }, self.checkIntervalInMilliseconds)
        }
      }
    )
  }
}

// Export our class
module.exports = waitForTextInCollection
```

This works for my use case, but I don't pretend it is as solid as it could be.  Hopefully it helps someone else.